# Why does ::before CSS Selector not work with list items when a item is added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, xhtml, html-lists

I have the following list:

```
<ul id="objects-list">
   <li>Table</li>
   <li>Chair</li>
   <li>Window</li>
</ul>
```

With the following CSS (taken from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp):

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 1em;
}
```

Which changes the default list marker to a red one.
Everything works fine, but when i add a new item to the list by Javascript using

```
var objectsList = document.getElementById("objects-list");
var listItem = document.createElement("LI");
listItem.innerHTML = "Pen";
objectsList.appendChild(listItem );
```

It happens in my XHTML file. It doesn't happen in a Stack Snippet.

The item is correctly added to the list, but with no marker at all. In addition, when i check the new item in the Inspector, it shows no "::before" element at all.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: On my  side is working - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/r89yq3jd/1/

Comment: I can't [reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/0j6m5nta/) the issue ..?

Comment: [I cannot replicate your issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Would you mind making a stack-snippet in the question to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: @LuísP.A. et. al. - It happens in XHTML, just not in HTML.

Comment: @ Maffe - If you're using XHTML as I suspect you are, please update the question to say that. (Don't get the wrong idea, it's understandable not to have thought to do that originally; it's just that it turns out to be relevant, so adding the tag and a note in the text will help future visitors.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to replicate your issue by using an [**XHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/XHTML) file.

The problem is that XHTML is *case-sensitive*, `li` != `LI`. Change your code adding the element to use `li`:

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li");
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
```

Here's a complete XHTML file demonstrating the problem. If you want to verify it locally, be sure to serve the file with the correct `Content-Type` (using the extension `.xhtml` and opening it from the file system also works, at least in Chrome and its variants):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>XHTML CSS Problem</title>
<style>
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 1em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="objects-list">
   <li>Table</li>
   <li>Chair</li>
   <li>Window</li>
</ul>
<script>
var objectsList = document.getElementById("objects-list");
var listItem = document.createElement("LI");
listItem.innerHTML = "Pen";
objectsList.appendChild(listItem );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```